# Tensorflow Keras Estimator fails on regression task while underlying model works

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator, tf.keras

I use a convolutional neural network for a regression task (i.e. the final layer of the network has one neuron with linear activation) and this works fine (enough). When I try to use the exact same model packaged with `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator`, the estimator seems to fit but the training loss stops decreasing very soon. The final eval losses (after 4 epochs each) are about 0.4 (mean abs. error) for the bare keras model and about 2.5 (mean abs. error) for the estimator.

To demonstrate the issue, I apply my model in both bare and estimator-packaged form to the MNIST dataset (I know that MNIST is a classification task and it doesn't really make sense to approach it as a regression task. The example should still illustrate my point.)

I find it very surprising, that, when using the same way to package a classification neural network into an estimator, the bare keras model and its packaged estimator version perform equally well (classification case is not included in the example code below). The difference only occurs for the regression task. I expect I'm either missing something pretty basic or this behaviour is due to some bug in Tensorflow.

To make sure there are as few differences as possible between the input to the models I package MNIST as a `tf.data.Dataset` and return it from an input function, which is passed to the estimator. For the bare Keras model, I use the same input function to obtain the `tf.Data.dataset` and give it directly to the `fit` function.

```
# python 3.6. Tested with tensorflow-gpu-1.14 and tensorflow-cpu-2.0
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def get_model(IM_WIDTH=28, num_color_channels=1):
    """Create a very simple convolutional neural network using a tf.keras Functional Model."""
    input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(IM_WIDTH, IM_WIDTH, num_color_channels))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')(input)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(3)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="mae",
                  metrics=['mae'])
    model.summary()
    return model


def input_fun(train=True):
    """Load MNIST and return the training or test set as a tf.data.Dataset; Valid input function for tf.estimator"""
    (train_images, train_labels), (eval_images, eval_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    train_images = train_images.reshape((60_000, 28, 28, 1)).astype(np.float32) / 255.
    eval_images = eval_images.reshape((10_000, 28, 28, 1)).astype(np.float32) / 255.
    # train_labels = train_labels.astype(np.float32)  # these two lines don't affect behaviour.
    # eval_labels = eval_labels.astype(np.float32)
    # For a neural network with one neuron in the final layer, it doesn't seem to matter if target data is float or int.

    if train:
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, train_labels))
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=100).repeat(None).batch(32).prefetch(1)
    else:
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((eval_images, eval_labels))
        dataset = dataset.batch(32).prefetch(1)  # note: prefetching does not affect behaviour

    return dataset


model = get_model()
train_input_fn = lambda: input_fun(train=True)
eval_input_fn = lambda: input_fun(train=False)

NUM_EPOCHS, STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 4, 1875  # 1875 = number_of_train_images(=60.000)  /  batch_size(=32)
USE_ESTIMATOR = False  # change this to compare model/estimator. Estimator performs much worse for no apparent reason
if USE_ESTIMATOR:
    estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(
        keras_model=model, model_dir="model_directory",
        config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=200, save_summary_steps=200))

    train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=STEPS_PER_EPOCH * NUM_EPOCHS)
    eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=eval_input_fn, throttle_secs=0)

    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)
    print("Training complete. Evaluating Estimator:")
    print(estimator.evaluate(eval_input_fn))
    # final train loss with estimator: ~2.5 (mean abs. error).
else:
    dataset = train_input_fn()
    model.fit(dataset, steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
    print("Training complete. Evaluating Keras model:")
    print(model.evaluate(eval_input_fn()))
    # final train loss with Keras model: ~0.4 (mean abs. error).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a bug report at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35833#issue-549185982

To avoid the discussion being split across websites I mark this topic as solved.

Answer (score 1):

I am providing the same answer that I provided in GitHub.

I agree with you that there is a significant difference between results from the model and the estimator if we use `TF1.15`. I think there may not be any more updates to `TF1.15` branch. If there is any security related issues, then only there will be updates to `TF1.15` branch.

I ran your code with `tf-nightly`. I don't see any significant difference between output from model and estimator.

The following is the output from the model (USE_ESTIMATOR = False)

```
Training complete. Evaluating Keras model:
313/313 [==============================] - 2s 7ms/step - loss: 0.4018 - mae: 0.4021
[0.4018059968948364, 0.4020615816116333]
```

The following is the output from the estimator (USE_ESTIMATOR = True)

```
Training complete. Evaluating Estimator:
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2020-03-18T23:15:15Z
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from model_directory/model.ckpt-7500
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Inference Time : 2.14818s
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2020-03-18-23:15:17
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 7500: global_step = 7500, loss = 0.39566746, mae = 0.39566746
INFO:tensorflow:Saving 'checkpoint_path' summary for global step 7500: model_directory/model.ckpt-7500
{'loss': 0.39566746, 'mae': 0.39566746, 'global_step': 7500}
```